# Convert 4 digit integer to decimal for money

Tags: php

I am trying to convert a 4 digit integer like `1999` to `19.99`.

I have looked at functions like `money_format()` but this seems to not be what I am looking for. Here is a function I wrote but there must be pre-existing method to do this?

```
function numberToDecimal((int)$num) {
    if(!preg_match('/^\d{4}$/', $num) return;
    $parsed = (string)$num;
    $i      = 0;
    $ret    = $parsed[$i++] . $parsed[$i++] . '.';
    $ret   .= $parsed[$i++] . $parsed[$i];
    return $ret;
}
```

Thank-you in advance. 
See the code working over at corresponding to the answer [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/kdnXI).

Comment: Wouldn't `1999 / 100` be enough?

Comment: Okay, that problem solving skills is top-notch and I am using it haha. Is there any pre-existing methods however? @ShiraNai7

Comment: Pre-existing method to divide a number by 100? I think this is as simple as it gets :)

Comment: I mean, to append the decimal pointer haha @ShiraNai7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the following:

```
$money = 1999 ;
echo number_format(($money /100), 2, '.', ' ');
// Will output: 19.99
```

Comment: That saved the day, I did not think twice about doing the division until @ShiraNai7 mentioned the solution. Thanks for the answer! Will mark it once I can.